Can an American option calendar spread have a negative price?
Consider an American put calendar spread on strike K with maturities T1 < T2. Is the longer-dated put always more expensive than the shorter-dated one?
How valid is the following no-arbitrage argument?
Assume P(K,T1) > P(K,T2). Then one could sell the put expiring on T1 and buy the put expiring on T2. Then, on T1, if spot S > K, then the T1 put expires worthless and you’re left with long the T2 put. If S <= K, you exercise the T2 put early and get assigned on the T1 put and are left with no position. In all cases, you have made at least the difference in price.
Are there some considerations on assignment of the T1 put that make this argument invalid?

This is a valid argument.

I'm a but confused - are you arguing that it is possible for P(K,T1) to be more expensive or that it cannot be more expensive because there would then be an arbitrage, and thus the mispricing would be arb-ed away?

I think you need to consider the (optimal) decision of the T1 buyer.
You are short T1 and long T2.
As soon as the T1 buyer exercises (you can't control that), you need to pay $(K - S)^+$, which you can get exercising your option at T2.
Obviously, if she exercises when her option is out of the money, you don't (and wait to make more money).
This way, you always have enough money to pay the T1.
